# How can we paginate using riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have **network request** to call with page , which approach would be better for **pagination** with riverpod using it for the first time , do i go with state notifier or change notifier for this please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On freecodecamp there is a detailed guide on how to implement infinite pagination using Riverpod, you should be able to follow it step by step:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/infinite-pagination-in-flutter-with-riverpod/

Comment: ok thanks will see it

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod_infinite_scroll its an open source, MIT licensed project that is actively maintained.

Comment: yes this plugin checked, very useful, little code and easy to use

Answer (score -1):

I believe [this](https://youtu.be/a5QU6cwMHpw) explains Better. No need for the Freeze Package. its uses just riverpod.